# BMW Adventure engine cut out and won't start.Has spark,fuel and compression.No fault codes.my question is motorbike related

Tags: motorcycle

Tried spraying fuel down air intake and it turned over quicker but did'nt fire up.If anybody knows some checks with picoscope and can describe the process would be gratefull.PS just bought the pico so still trying to find my way round it,thanks Pete.